# How would you solve this task of a pneumatic machine?

Tags: pneumatic

Engineering student here.
Pardon the lack of knowledge in English :)

**So the objective is**:
When you click on the **Start** Button then it turns Cylinder C **on** and then Cylinder B **on**, later it turns Cylinder C **off** and then turns Cylinder B **off**. This should go in a **loop** until you press the **Stop** Button.

We have:
Two Buttons, Two cylinders, One 3/2 valve, Two 5/2 valves.
Four "buttons- ish" for the cylinders (two each, one already pressed by default and the other is just in front which can be pressed when a cylinder is on).
Also air supply. Just look at the picture below to understand better.

So how would you solve this?
(BTW ignore whatever is already drawn by me).

Would appreciate a drawn answer with a simple explanation.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: "*Would appreciate a drawn answer with a simple explanation.*" Sorry, that's not the way it works here. We won't do your homework for you. You need to show your own work and ask questions when you get stuck. Please [Edit] your question and add your own work. Start by drawing the air supply. Then label each of the valves and roller switches.

Comment: `how would you solve this?` asks for an opinion ... it is also not a question about a pneumatic machine, but a question about problem solving process